# Define word at the end of the file - Assembly / C++

Tags: assembly, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to write a boot sector in C++. In order to do this, I must add the word 0xaa55 at the end of the binary. C++ allows the use of inline assembly through the "__asm" keyword followed by curly braces. This places the assembly code wherever it was written in the c++ source code. I want to be able to define a word at the end of the file using the "dw" command. How can I do this when C++ generates assembly code around the inline assembly on compilation? I'm using Windows 10 Visual Studio 2017 for development. I am currently using Microsoft's C++ compiler. Thanks!

Comment: Actually, now that I think about this, I'm not exactly sure that this will work. Anyway, hopefully you guys can help. All I really want to do is add a word at the end of the file, without adding code to the end of the file.

Comment: It is unclear what you are really asking, and it almost seems like an X-Y problem. Why are you trying to do this in the first place?. You show no code with an attempt to demonstrate what it is you are trying to achieve. You also don't mention what C++ compiler (inline assembly can different among compilers) or what processor and OS this is for.

Comment: Sorry. I wasn't sure exactly what I wanted when I asked the question to begin with. I am trying to write a boot sector in c++. To do this, I need to write a word to the end of the file - 0xaa55 - but when using inline c++, it puts the assembly where I put it in the .cpp file. I need to be able to define the word at the end of the file.

Comment: Are you using g++ (GNU C++) for this? Or MSVC++? Or Watcom C++ DJGPP? What operating system are you doing development on? Windows? Linux? DOS? OS/X? (or some other OS?)

Comment: Your edit still doesn't say what Compiler you are using. The edit suggests you might be using Microsoft VC++ (it could even be OS/X although not likely)

Comment: I'm developing on Windows 10 through Visual Studio 2017. The compiler is made by Microsoft

Comment: So you are using Microsoft C++. I can tell you that what you are doing won't work (I do understand that you want to place the 0xaa55 boot signature in the last 2 bytes of a 512 byte sector destined to be placed on a disk/disk image). The primary problem is that Microsoft C++ hasn't supported 16-bit code generation for over 15 years. The C++ that could generate 16-bit real mode code was Visual C++ 1.42c.

Comment: Oh. So, would it be possible to switch the compiler in visual studio then?

Comment: No, you'd have to acquire an old copy of Visual C++ (1.52c being the last one that supported 16-bit code generation). It is an entriely different IDE and can't be dropped in easily within a modern VS without a bunch of hassles. Visual C++ 1.52c is a 16-bit program as well so won't run directly on Windows 10 without an emulator or VM. Even then you'd need to find a linker that can do what you are looking for. There is another option and that is OpenWatcom C++ that I believe still generates 16-bit code (I know OpenWatcom C does).

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'll look into that :)

Comment: Bootloaders are most easily don't in assembly.

Comment: I haven't explored this Code project thoroughly but they seem to tell you the type of software you would need (particular old compilers) and assemblers. https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36907/How-to-develop-your-own-Boot-Loader#_Toc231383170

Comment: Thanks, Michael Petch!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is impossible. The problems are legion:

You can't accomplish your *immediate* task, because there's no way to force Microsoft's C++ compiler to emit a certain sequence of bytes at the end of the code. You just don't have fine enough control over this when you're writing in C++. The syntax doesn't exist to express it, and even if it did, you wouldn't have any guarantee that the compiler/linker would comply with it and emit the bytes in the correct spot.

Furthermore, bootloader code is very particular on the x86, and has to be written to a very precise format. In addition to needing these two signature bytes at the end, you also need to make sure that the proper sequence of instructions are found at the *beginning* of the boot sector (which you can't get the C++ compiler to emit, either), *and* you need to make sure that the entire boot sector is exactly 512 bytes (padded out to the end, where the final two bytes are 0xAA55). You can't get MSVC to produce code that is exactly 512 bytes in size. There's no way to enforce the length, and even if there were, the C++ code will be much larger than that because…

MSVC's toolchain (compiler & linker) don't provide any way to generate "raw" binary files. Pretty much the only thing they create is Win32 PE-format executables, which will have a bunch of headers and stuff that you don't need and don't want in a bootloader. I suppose you could go back and strip this stuff out with a hex editor, but once you're doing that, you might as well just write the darn thing in assembly language and get exactly what you want.

Also, MSVC's toolchain hasn't supported the generation of 16-bit code (as is required for a bootloader, since the x86 CPU starts up in 16-bit mode for compatibility) for nearly 25 years. The last version that can generate 16-bit code is Visual C++ 1.52c, designed for Windows 3.1. You can probably find this for download somewhere on "abandonware" websites. The legality of this is dubious, but I must say that I *personally* don't have a problem with it if you have a legitimate license for a modern version of Visual Studio. However, you may run into problems getting it to run on modern versions of Windows, which means you'll need to set up a Windows 3.1 (or maybe 95) virtual machine. And even once you get VC++ 1.52c set up, you won't be home-free, because the C++ compiler/linker *still* wasn't designed to create raw binaries or produce bootloaders. You *still* won't have the fine-grained level of control that you need.

Bootloaders should really be written in assembly language. Since they can be at most 512 bytes, and what they do is not very complicated, and most of the documentation you find online assumes assembly language anyway, this is really not as daunting of an exercise as it might sound. If you have the requisite knowledge to write a bootloader, then you either already know enough assembly or it's time that you got your feet wet in it.

Now, all versions of Visual C++ have shipped with Microsoft's Macro Assembler (MASM), which is exactly what you want—a way to assemble your assembly-language code into a raw binary file. Problem is, MASM hasn't supported 16-bit code generation since version 6.0-ish, shipped with VC++ 1.52c (and also sold separately). Again, you can download these old versions on various "abandonware" sites, and you will probably have fewer issues running it on a modern machine, since it's a simple command-line binary (although you won't be able to run it at all on a 64-bit version of Windows, since it is all 16-bit code). But you should beware that you're using obsolete software that is no longer supported, not to mention the use of which is legally dubious, so you might want to reconsider.

You would be much better off using a different assembler. [NASM](http://www.nasm.us) is a very good choice. There's *tons* of sample bootloader code written in NASM-format assembly language. Our own Michael Petch has written hundreds of answers here on Stack Overflow that cover this topic into the ground. An alternative to NASM is [Open Watcom](http://openwatcom.org), the modern, open-source re-release of the classic Watcom toolchain. Watcom's C/C++ compiler was "best-of-class" in its day for optimized code, but more importantly for your purposes, comes with an assembler (WASM) that can build 16-bit binaries. There isn't as much help available online for Open Watcom, although there is a little bit, and the syntax is essentially MASM-compatible. Both of these will run fine on modern versions of Windows (or also OS X, or Linux, or OS/2, …).

Comment: Thank you for your very comprehensive answer! I understand that it would make sense to write the boot loader in assembly, but the problem was that I wanted to be able to use C++ as well. As I understand it, OpenWatcom supports C++ and Assembly which would be exactly what I want.

Comment: Actually MASM never dropped support for 16-bit code generation. You can generate 16-bit code with the version of MASM included in with Visual Studio 2017 by using the `/omf` option (or even to a limited extent without it). The problem is that Visual Studio doesn't include a linker capable of generate binary output, it can only generate PECOFF executables. You need to use to use some other linker, like Microsoft's old segmented linker (of which there is a Win32 version), in order to generate a binary ".COM" file that you can use as boot sector.

Comment: Can you please send me a link? Thanks!